# Building a SQL query that doesn't include data based on hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've spent quite a bit of time on Google and SO the last few days, but I can't seem to find an answer to my problem. Not knowing exactly how to phrase the issue into a reasonable question makes it a little more difficult. You don't know what you don't know, right?

Due to business limitations I can't post my exact code and database structure, so I'll do my best to give a solid example.

**Customer Table** - Holds customer data

```
[CustId] | [CustName]  
---------------------
1        | John Smith  
2        | Jane Doe
3        | John Doe
```

**Code Table** - Holds code data

```
[CodeId] | [CodeDesc]
---------------------
A        | A Desc
B        | B Desc
C        | C Desc
D        | D Desc
E        | E Desc
```

**CustomerCode Table** - Combines customers with codes

```
[CustId] | [CodeId]
-------------------
1        | A
1        | B
2        | B
2        | C
2        | D
3        | C
3        | E
```

**CodeHierarchy Table** - Hierarchy of codes that shouldn't be included (DropCode) if a customer has a ConditionCode

```
[ConditionCode] | [DropCode]
----------------------------
A               | B
B               | C
B               | D
```

Now I'll try to explain my actual question.

What I'm trying to accomplish is writing a query (view) that will list codes based on the CodeHierarchy table.

Results would be something like this:

```
[CustName] | [CodeId]
-------------------
John Smith | A
Jane Doe   | B
John Doe   | C
John Doe   | E
```

Code B isn't listed for John Smith since he has code A. Codes C and D aren't listed for Jane Doe since she also has code B. John Doe has all codes listed (notice that E isn't even in the CodeHierarchy table).

I've tried a few different things (inner joins, left/right joins, subqueries, etc) but I just can't get the results I'm looking.

As a base query, this returns all codes:

```
SELECT 
    Customer.CustomerName, 
    Code.CodeDesc  
FROM 
    Customer 
        INNER JOIN CustomerCode
            ON Customer.CodeId = CustomerCode.CodeId
        INNER JOIN Code
            ON CustomerCode.CodeId = Code.CodeId
```

This only returns codes that are ConditionCodes (I understand why, but I though it might be worth a shot at the time):

```
SELECT 
    Customer.CustomerName, 
    Code.CodeDesc  
FROM 
    Customer 
        INNER JOIN CustomerCode
            ON Customer.CodeId = CustomerCode.CodeId
        INNER JOIN Code
            ON CustomerCode.CodeId = Code.CodeId
        INNER JOIN CodeHierarchy
            ON Customer.CodeId = CodeHierarchy.ConditionCode
            AND Customer.CodeId != CodeHierarchy.DropCode
```

I tried a subquery (don't have that code available) that ended up dropping all DropCodes, regardless if a member did or did not have a qualifying hierarchy (i.e. customer rows with B weren't returned even if they didn't have A)

I had an idea of making the base query above a subquery and the joining it with the CodeHierarchy table, but I'm stuck on how to write the query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        base query (with all codes)
    ) CustomerCodesAll
        INNER/LEFT JOIN CodeHierarchy
            ON ?
```

I've also been doing some reading on CTEs, but I'm not sure how I could make use of that technique.

This will end up being a view to be queried against for reporting purposes. The customer table contains much more data including dob, gender, company status, etc. The view will be  straightforward and pull everything. Queries against the view will include where clauses for dob, gender, etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Customer.CustName, 
    Code.CodeDesc
FROM 
    Customer 
        INNER JOIN CustomerCode AS posCustomerCode
            ON Customer.CustId = posCustomerCode.CustId
        INNER JOIN Code
            ON posCustomerCode.CodeId = Code.CodeId
        LEFT JOIN CodeHierarchy
            ON posCustomerCode.CodeId = CodeHierarchy.DropCode

WHERE 
    CodeHierarchy.ConditionCode NOT IN (
      SELECT CodeId 
      FROM CustomerCode AS negCustomerCode
      WHERE negCustomerCode.CustId=posCustomerCode.CustId
     )
     OR CodeHierarchy.ConditionCode IS NULL
```

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1981/11)

Comment: Worked like a charm. I guess I was overcomplicating it. Thanks!